# Oracle Apex - change color of cards

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, apex

The image:

[image]

shows a snippet of a dashboard from oracle apex. In the image you can see a 6 boxes and grey cards (the circles in each box at the top right corner) which contain a number inside of them. There is a way to conditionally change the color of the grey circle through **sql** as the circle is defined as a card. That means I can operate with the help of this link https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/color-and-status-modifiers.

My question is, if there is way to conditionally change the color of each box instead of the round card. I want to do that because there is no correlation between the color of the card and the number inside of it.
An alternative would be to change the color of the text (which I had to censor) either next to the circle or in the **subbox**.

Comment: Please, no images (or links to them.) Provide sample table data and expected result as formatted text instead. [mcve]

Comment: This is similar to a question you asked yesterday. Please don't delete questions and re-post them. People put time in writing a proper answer. If you delete it, the answer is lost and cannot be seen by other members anymore. I asked a couple of questions for your previous question but never got an answer. Please document the apex version and type of region used

Comment: Hi, i deleted the previous question because many things seemed to be unclear. The patch version is from 2020.11.17 (20.1.0.00.13)

Comment: What is the region type ? What is the template ? What are the template options ? Please provide as much info as possible (in the question, not in the comments). This question isn't much clearer than the previous one :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask